# how to flat nested objects keys with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi everyone I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-joana-loyvl8)

I want to show my `DefaultValue` nested objects like this

["DefaultValue", "DefaultValue", "DefaultValue","DefaultValue","DefaultValue","DefaultValue"]

I have following data from backend:

```
    const data = [
     {
      id: 243,
      Name: "test",
      type: "checkbox",
      DefaultValue: {
        DefaultValue: {
          DefaultValue: {
            DefaultValue: {
              DefaultValue: {
                DefaultValue: ["a"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
    ];
```

So I am trying to do following, but it's not works, its says like Cannot convert undefined or null to object

```
    const innerObject = o => {
     return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
      return typeof o[k] === 'object' ? innerObject(o[k]) : ((r[k] = o[k]), r);
     }, {});
    };
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: First, your question is a bit unclear. Second, `array` is of type `"object"`. Third, you are  overwriting values and not adding in various levels

Comment: Another issue with your code for which you are getting error is that `data` is an array. So `data.DefaultValue` is undefined. You will have to do `data[0].DefaultValue` For your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-sunset-m7q9yp

Comment: Thanks for notes. So backend is returning me data which have nested defaultValue objects (some time it can be nested 5 times another time 3 time ..etc) ....I need just understand the count and print them in array like this `["DefaultValue", "DefaultValue", "DefaultValue","DefaultValue","DefaultValue","DefaultValue"]`

Comment: in my case it nested 6 times, that why I am printing array which have 6 `defaultvalue`

Comment: So to understand correct, you only care about `DefaultValue`? or all keys in general

Comment: Can you also clarify about `data` itself being an array? I assume you would have multiple objects within this array? Can you show what your expected output is when there are multiple objects within `data` if this can occur?

Comment: @Rajesh only DefaultvValue key

Comment: @NickParsons in my case I am getting data from backend which have `id`, `name`, `type` and `defaultvalue` . some time default values can be nested 1 time , 2 time ...10 time ,,,, etc .... I need to understand the count of that nested objects and print only keys .... in my case it nested 6 time and my expected result should be` ["DefaultValue", "DefaultValue", "DefaultValue","DefaultValue","DefaultValue","DefaultValue"]`...

Comment: @someone I understand that, but in your question you've shown that `data` is an array. What I'm trying to understand is what your output should be for when you have multiple objects within that array: `const data = [ {id: 243, Name: ...}, {id: 123, Name: ...}, ...]` etc all with similar structures to the object you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
const data = [
     {
      id: 243,
      Name: "test",
      type: "checkbox",
      DefaultValue: {
        DefaultValue: {
          DefaultValue: {
            DefaultValue: {
              DefaultValue: {
                DefaultValue: ["a"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
     }
    ];
    
    const makeArr = (obj, arr = []) =>{
        if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null){
            arr.push('DefaultValue');
           return makeArr(obj.DefaultValue, arr)
        }else{
            return arr;
        }
    }
    
    console.log(makeArr(data[0].DefaultValue))
```